# groovysh is giving java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Groovy version:
Groovy Version: 3.0.0-rc-3 JVM: 1.8.0_221 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

on running command : groovysh 
Error output:

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:106)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:124)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path, /tmp/libjansi-64-3695606470401720252.so: /tmp/libjansi-64-3695606470401720252.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted]
        at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:182)
        at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:140)
        at org.fusesource.jansi.internal.CLibrary.<clinit>(CLibrary.java:42)
        at org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole.wrapOutputStream(AnsiConsole.java:48)
        at org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole.<clinit>(AnsiConsole.java:38)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.lambda$createCallStaticSite$2(CallSiteArray.java:65)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:63)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:156)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Main.installAnsi(Main.groovy:249)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Main.setTerminalType(Main.groovy:235)
        at org.apache.groovy.groovysh.Main.main(Main.groovy:120)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: I am not saying, that it will fix it, but why not try the 3.0.0 instead of the RC?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this kind of issue comes not from Groovy itself, but from your user not having write rights to /tmp. For example if your tmp is mounted readonly.

Background: Jansi requires native libraries, that are part of the jar. Java cannot load them form the jar and requires them to be put "somewhere", which is usually /tmp. Since it seems your tmp cannot be written you get the "Operation not permitted".